# Hibernate : nullPointerException on my entityManager with @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I must have done something wrong. I'm looking since hours but i can't find my problem. I'm trying to use @PersistenceContext for my entityManager but all i got is a nullPointerException.

Here is my class and the method where i get the error :

```
@Repository
public class ApplicationDao extends Dao
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    [...]

    public ArrayList<Application> getListApplication() {

        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        [...]

    }   

    [...]
}
```

Maybe is it my Spring configuration because i got this error since a long time when i load my project but it never cause any problem

```
SEVERE: Spring context lookup failed, skipping spring component provider initialization.
```

My configuration files :

src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

  <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.calamar.beans" />

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="url" />
    <property name="username" value="calamar" />
    <property name="password" value="calamar" />
  </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="calamar" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>


</beans>
```

src/main/resources/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="calamar" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.calamar.beans.Application</class>
        <class>com.calamar.beans.Derogation</class>
        <class>com.calamar.beans.DerogationFille</class>
        <class>com.calamar.beans.DerogationAutre</class>
        <class>com.calamar.beans.DerogationLinux</class>
        <class>com.calamar.beans.DerogationOracle</class>
        <class>com.calamar.beans.MatriculeUser</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="myUrl"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myUsername"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="myPassword"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="calamarantoine"/>

            <!-- Permet de reduire le temps de lancement de entityManagerFactory -->
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />

        </properties>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>/*Company group id*/</groupId>
    <artifactId>calamar</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>calamar Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <parent>
        //Company parent group
    </parent>


    <dependencyManagement>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jsp : Jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Servlet api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring boot test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring boot jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL & Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- company dependencies -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>calamar</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven compiler with java 1.8 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">  <display-name>Calamar</display-name>
    <display-name>Calamar</display-name>
    <filter>
        //Company filter
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        //[...]
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    //Servlets
</web-app>
```

Thank you for taking time to help me.

Comment: Can you add your configuration?

Comment: I added my configuration files to the post. (Sorry if I was long to respond)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the error, the problem is with Spring configuration, not hibernate.

Comment: I added my configuration files to the first post, so you can help me finding why i got this error. (Sorry if I was long to respond)

Comment: I would suggest to switch from a xml configuration to a java configuration. Your configuration looks ok, but it could have an error which is harder to debug when using xml. If you can switch to java, you can find where is the problem faster. Cheers

Comment: Only switching applicationContext.xml and keeping web.xml persistence.xml and pom.xml the same ?

Comment: I would just keep pom.xml, everything else I would switch it to java

Comment: Word of caution. Web.xml is optional only on Servlet 3.0 containers. Servers like weblogic 10,11 still uses Servlet 2.5. If you are using tomcat, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration works for me. Can you check it. Persistence context is not injected in ur case for some reason.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>                 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
     <property name="jndiName" value="myDs"/>       
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>

</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDs"/> 
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.vimal.ecommerce.domain"/>
</bean>
```